# Failed to Install Python 3.7.2 on macOS 10.14.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I install python 3.7.2 by pyenv

```
pyenv install 3.7.2
python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.7.2.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.2/Python-3.7.2.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.2...
python-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.2 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/ql/l7pj2ssj7j3ctsx3lqt99cwc0000gn/T/python-build.20190129200315.73913
Results logged to /var/folders/ql/l7pj2ssj7j3ctsx3lqt99cwc0000gn/T/python-build.20190129200315.73913.log

Last 10 log lines:
    fi
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000000111ac65c0 (most recent call first):
/bin/sh: line 1: 85109 Abort trap: 6           ./python.exe -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars
generate-posix-vars failed
make: *** [pybuilddir.txt] Error 1
```

Same error when I build it from source code manually

```
$ ./configure
$ make
./python.exe -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars ;\
    if test $? -ne 0 ; then \
        echo "generate-posix-vars failed" ; \
        rm -f ./pybuilddir.txt ; \
        exit 1 ; \
    fi
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000000115df55c0 (most recent call first):
/bin/sh: line 1: 43771 Abort trap: 6           ./python.exe -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars
generate-posix-vars failed
make: *** [pybuilddir.txt] Error 1
```

I also have python2 and python3 installed by homebrew.

and have xcode developer tools `xcode-select -p`
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools